# C# Organising and structuring of the code

Tags: c#, structure

I am quite new to c# and Visual studio and am not sure how to best structure the code so I  would very much apreciate tips and guidance so that I am not start to build something on a weak foundation.I am trying to create an application that:

1. Read data from a WebSocket
2. Store the data in a DataTable, and do calculations with the data that will be stored in new DataTables
3. Present the data + calculations in a Chart

This is how I have structured it so far:

```
    private Data data;
    private WebSocket ws;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Class data that holds dataset with datatables, and that have access to the chart
    data = new Data(chart);

    // WebSocket class that retrieves data and stores it in a private object "Dataobject" and calls the data class on an onChange event. The data class then stores the data in the DataTable/DataSet  
    ws = new WebSocket(data);

    // Method that binds the DataTable(s) to the chart
    data.print();
}
```

Since the WebSocket works in a different thread the call to the data class from the WebSocket class is made like this:

```
    private void Dataobject_ValueChanged(bool value)
    {
        threadsafe();
    }
    public void threadsafe()
    {
        if (data.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action safeWrite = delegate { threadsafe(); };
            data.Invoke(safeWrite);
        }
        else
        {
            data.AddRow(dataobject);
        }
    }
```

Am I on the correct path or are there better ways? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: A lot of this falls down to preference of course, but in general you should always follow the rule that you should do everything to make the code self explanatory and boring. "The quality of code is measured in the amount of 'WTF moments' that you experience while reading it"*

**Comments**

The comments that you used for the properties should be shortened very much. They are too wordy and even if you have to use long comments, I would recommend you spread them over multiple lines.

If you comment fields of a class you should use the documentation comment syntax to make the IDE detect the comment and display it with the field / property when you use it later in the code.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Some text to better understand the use of this field.
/// </summary>
private int someField;
```

Although in general I would recommend making your code speak and not use comments for that. So e.g. if you have a variable which is used as a flag to indicate whether the object x is active, you should call that variable something like `isActive` and not have a comment explaining that, because the variable speaks for itself.

**Indentation**

I'm not sure if it's just a copy-paste mistake, but in your first code snippet you have uneven indentation which is not ideal. Inside a block you should always have the same indent level, expect maybe if some line of code is too long and you split it up into two lines.

**Spaces / Empty lines**

In your second code snippet, there's no space between the two methods. I would always recommend adding an empty newline after a closing bracket, expect for `if { } else { }` statements or a few other rare cases. But e.g. directly after an if statement I would add an empty newline and definitely between methods.

**Naming**

You should also name variables, fields, methods, etc. consistently. Your method `threadsafe` is all lower-case, but other methods before start with an upper-case letter. In C# you normally use pascal case for your methods and also for properties, so starting with an upper-case letter and then separating each word with an upper-case letter. Other things like variables will normally be camel-cased (starting with a lower-case letter, the rest same as pascal-case).

**Inline Delegates**

Often it is unnecessary to have code spread over multiple lines. Your `safeWrite` delegate is an example of that. In this case your delegate only does one thing and is not very complex. It doesn't need further explanation through a name, etc. You could therefore instead just use an inline delegate like this:

```cs
data.Invoke(() => threadsafe());
```

There's many other things to be said about code formatting and styling. There's also many opinions on how to structure your code, but as I mentioned in the disclaimer: As long as you reduce confusion and reduce the complexity of your program, you're on a good track.

As a ending note, I think you should inform yourself about 'clean code'. I can recommend Uncle Bob's videos and talks on that topic, they can help you significantly with improving the way you write you're code.

Comment: Thank you for the input. The comments was added with the intention of making this question easier to follow. I dont have them in my code, and the Indentations Visual Studio handles very good IMO. :-) 

I understand now that my question was not very clear and for that I apologize. I was wondering if its good practise to keep data and datasets in one class, like I do. If its good practise to keep the WebSocket in one class like I do. If there are better ways to derive them. Shall i instead use partial classes or other techniques...and so on.

Comment: Oh sorry ;) ... I suppose my answer does miss the point...I don't think I am competent enough to answer your actual question though, sorry